# Saving blob column to file using dynamic SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to save a blob column into a file.

As you know, the `SELECT blobColumn INTO DUMPFILE` does not allow variables, so I have to write a dynamic SQL statement.

But I do not know how to refer to external value.

This is my not working code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchAndExport;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAndExport(IN search VARCHAR(255), IN limitOutput INT)
BEGIN
    -- Handlers
    DECLARE eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    
    -- Outputs
    DECLARE emailId CHAR(36);
    DECLARE eml LONGBLOB;
    
    -- Cursor / Search Select
    -- TODO: This is a sample only for debug
    DECLARE emails CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT Id,RawContent FROM Email
      LIMIT limitOutput;
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = TRUE;

    OPEN emails;
    SELECT CONCAT('SearchTextInContentAndDump: Search ''',search,'''. Limit: ',limitOutput,'. Saving files in ',@@global.secure_file_priv) log;
    emailLoop: LOOP
        FETCH emails INTO emailId, eml;
        IF eof THEN 
            LEAVE emailLoop;
        END IF;
    SELECT CONCAT('Saving email: ',@@global.secure_file_priv,emailId);
    SET @savesql := CONCAT('SELECT @eml INTO DUMPFILE ''',@@global.secure_file_priv,emailId,'.eml''');
    PREPARE dyn FROM @savesql;
    EXECUTE dyn;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE dyn;

    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE emails;

END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL SearchAndExport('Test',5);
```

If I use `SELECT @eml INTO DUMPFILE` it seems to work, but generates empty files. If I use `SELECT eml INTO DUMPFILE` (without @) it generates a syntax error. The eml variable contains valid value, because if I do a simple 'SELECT eml' inside the loop it returns de BLOB column.

Comment: You need to concatenate the value of eml into the sql enclosed by single quotes. eml and @eml are two different variables.

Comment: Local variable (`eml`) is NOT visible in/by prepared stmt. Use user-defined variable (`@eml`) in both retrieving code (instead of `eml`) and dynamic SQL..